# ASG Target Tracking policy based on the SUM of two (custom) metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling

I want my target tracking policy to be based on the CPU utilization of my ASG. I know that EC2 provides basic monitoring including a `CPUUtilization` metric but only at a 5-minute rate. I also know that I could enable detailed monitoring for all instances to enable metrics at a 1-minute interval but as far as I understand this is a "all or nothing" type of thing where I have to pay for ALL the EC2 metrics (network, etc.) as custom metrics (for my instance type there are 16 metrics which means 16 * $0.3 = $4.8 of additional cost / month / instance. please correct me if my assumption is wrong).

So, instead I use the CloudWatch agent running on the ASG instances with the following `amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json` config:

```json
...
"metrics": {
    "namespace": "AWS/EC2",
    "append_dimensions": {
        "AutoScalingGroupName": "$${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
        "InstanceId": "$${aws:InstanceId}"
    },
    "aggregation_dimensions": [
        ["AutoScalingGroupName"]
    ],
    "metrics_collected": {
        ...
        "cpu": {
            "measurement": [
                {
                    "name": "cpu_usage_user",
                    "rename": "CPUUtilizationUser"
                },
                {
                    "name": "cpu_usage_system",
                    "rename": "CPUUtilizationSystem"
                }
            ],
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "resources": ["*"],
            "totalcpu": true
        }
    }
}
```

The sum of `CPUUtilizationUser` and `CPUUtilizationSystem` closely matches the actual CPU utilization and I only pay for 2 additional custom metrics per instance instead of 16 (again, please correct me if the assumption is wrong).

**Question is how to use the sum of those two custom metrics for the target tracking policy of my ASG? I know you can use math expressions for CloudWatch alarms, but I don't see that for scaling policies.**

Note that I use Terraform to provision all my AWS resources including the scaling policy. Currently it looks like this:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "target_tracking" {
  ...
  policy_type = "TargetTrackingScaling"

  target_tracking_configuration {
    customized_metric_specification {
      metric_name = // here I want CPUUtilizationUser + CPUUtilizationSystem basically
      namespace = "AWS/EC2"
      statistic = "Average"
      metric_dimension {
        name  = "AutoScalingGroupName"
        value = aws_autoscaling_group.application.name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?
Many thanks!